# How to test the DOM of an inner <template> in vuejs with vitest?

Tags: vuejs2, vitest

I couldn't find a way to test that the following `amazingTitle` is getting rendered:

```
<template>
   <b-toast
     ... all the b-toast props 
   >
     <template #toast-title>
       <span class="my-cool-title">
          {{ amazingTitle }}
       </span>
     </template>
     <div>
        <span class="something-else">
           {{ somethingElse }}
        </span>
     </div>
   </b-toast>
</template>
```

I did manage to test the `somethingElse` though with the following:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

const wrapper = mount(MySuperCoolComponent, { propsData: { ... } });

const span = wrapper.find('.something-else').element;
```

but the same does not work for the `.my-cool-title` class and I suspect it's because it's within that second/inner template tag, however that's just a wild guess since I'm new to vuejs and I'm not really sure why I'm not able to test the `amazingTitle`.

Comment: [VTU Slots documentation](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/slots).